# How to startup application without opening window

Tags: startup, window

I'd like to add some startup applications without the windows opening immediately upon login. I'm not sure what commands to include with the startup to do so, if it's possible.

Right now, there's only two applications I'm trying to do this with: Mailspring and Whatsdesk. When the windows are closed with both, the processes are still open and can be accessed within from the Top Bar.

Right now, I just have the commands to open them in the startup applications which are just "mailspring" & "whatsdesk", but this opens the windows when logging in and I'd just like to have them be accessible from the top bar without the window opening upon login.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Which applications (different applications will most certainly behave differently)? Please **[edit]** your question and clarify?

Comment: I edited the question. Tried to be as clear as possible. Seems like a simple task but I'm not sure if there's commands to do them

Comment: So you want to open the programs in the background without them popping up on the screen?

Comment: Normally this is done with a "--background" or "--start-minimized" or similar command-line option to the program.  Unfortunately I don't see such an option for whatsdesk.

Comment: Yes. I'd just like to open them in the background. Not sure what commands are used for that though